# React-Native and ListView inside ScrollView

Tags: listview, scrollview, react-native

I have to show a series of vertical ListView, and the user should navigate horizontally between them.

The *horizontal* scroll must be performed *only* for some events, like the touch of a button.

The *vertical* one of the ListViews must be completely droved by user's gestures.

I tried to obtain this effect configuring a ScrollView as horizontal and putting inside it the ListViews, but I found out that the *vertical* scroll results completely disabled.

How can I obtain the desired behavior? 
Is there a ScrollView or ListView option I don't know about?
Should I change all the layout's structure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comes out that a vertical ListView (or ScrollView) inside an horizontal ScrollView will never work, until you set a value for the height (ex height: 400).

Hope this could help somebody else.

Comment: height for whom? set height for my horizontal scrollView and for the vertical listView and nothing works